# Using 2 sets of brackets to slice

Tags: python-2.7, slice

Python 2.7:

I'm working on Project Euler #011 and have found code that I know works, but have come up short finding *how* it works.

```
for i in xrange(17):
    # top-left to bottom-right
    add(grid[i*20::21])
    add(grid[i::21][:20-i])  # <---a

    # top-right to bottom-left
    add(grid[3+i::19][:i+4])
    add(grid[39+i::19][i:])  # <---b
```

My question is: how do the second set of brackets function at a and b?  I know they limit the number of list entries, but HOW!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first slice operation results in a sequence. The second slice operation slices that sequence. It's like `a + b + c`, but with slicing instead of addition.